# How do I get a value adjacent to a Max(value) using Linq?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a table:

```
Group | BasalArea | SpeciesName
1     | 3.6       | Palustris
1     | 45.0      | MSO
2     | 4.2       | Oak
2     | 2.0       | MSO
...
```

From this table, I would like to get the species name with the highest basal area grouped by the Group field, which would look like this:

```
Group | BasalArea | SpeciesName
1     | 45.0      | MSO
2     | 4.2       | Oak
```

Using SQL, I can get the highest basal area:

```
SELECT Group, Max(BasalArea)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY Group
```

I can't figure out how to also get the species name without doing some looping.  Is this possible?  What are the strategies for handling ties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simpler in LINQ2SQL than in SQL:

```
var res = source.MyTable
    .GroupBy(item => item.Group)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(item => item.BasalArea).First())
    .ToList();
```

This will return the list of items with largest values of `BasalArea` in its `Group`, together with `SpeciesName`.

In SQL you would need to join back to the original table, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE b
JOIN (
    SELECT Group, Max(BasalArea) as BasalArea
    FROM TABLE
    GROUP BY Group
) t on t.Group = b.Group AND t.BasalArea = b.BasalArea
```

Comment: Thanks for doing it in both Linq and SQL.  It's useful to see it both ways.

Comment: @canisrufus I edited the answer to replace `OrderBy` with `OrderByDescending` to make sure that you get the `max` rather than the `min`.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you direct me to a resource that would help me gain facility with LINQ?  I've read through and typed in some of the [101 examples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b), but I'd like something more comprehensive.

Comment: @canisrufus It's hard to beat the 101 examples. On the other hand, pretty much everything that I know about LINQ comes from [this tiny book](http://www.amazon.com/Linq-Pocket-Reference-OReilly/dp/0596519249). There's also a [great source of LINQ exercises that are both fun and real-world](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linq) :):):):)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var froup = categories.GroupBy(g => new {g.CategoryType})
                          .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(i => i.CategoryID).First())
                          .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

What sasblinkenlight said would be the LINQ. Out of curiosity, here is a potential SQL solution.

```
SELECT grouped.Group, raw.SpeciesName, grouped.MaBasalArea
FROM (
        SELECT Group, MAX(BasalArea) as MaxBasalArea
        FROM TABLE
        GROUP BY Group
     ) grouped
INNER JOIN TABLE raw ON grouped.MaxBasalArea = raw.BasalArea AND grouped.Group = raw.Group
```